# How to find max value Alphabet from DataFrame apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

i am trying to get the max value Alphabet from a panda dataframe as whole. I am not interested in what row or column it came from. I am just interested in a single max value within the dataframe.

This is what it looks like:

```
id conditionName
1     C
2     b
3     A
4     A
5     A
```

expected result is:

```
|id|conditionName|
+--+-------------+
| 3|   A         |
| 4|   A         |
| 5|   A         |
+----------------+
```

because 'A' is the first letter of the alphabet

> ```
> df= df.withColumn("conditionName", col("conditionName").cast("String"))
>     .groupBy("id,conditionName").max("conditionName");
> df.show(false);
> ```
>
> Exception: "conditionName" is not a numeric column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;

I need the max from an entire dataframe Alphabet character.
What should I use, so that the desired results?

Thank advance !

Comment: what is expected output? and what is your definition of `"max value from Alphabet"`

Comment: I'm sorry, I will edit its, Thank for your remind !

Comment: still unclear why, is it because `"A"` is the first letter of the alphabet or because it has highest count?

Comment: because "A" is the first letter of the alphabet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your `DataFrame` by your string column, grab the first value and use it to filter your original data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, desc, first

# we need lower() because ordering strings is case sensitive
first_letter = df.orderBy((lower(df["condition"]))) \
                 .groupBy() \
                 .agg(first("condition").alias("condition")) \
                 .collect()[0][0]

df.filter(df["condition"] == first_letter).show()
#+---+---------+
#| id|condition|
#+---+---------+
#|  3|        A|
#|  4|        A|
#|  5|        A|
#+---+---------+
```

Or more elegantly using `Spark SQL`:

```
df.registerTempTable("table")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * 
                FROM table 
                WHERE lower(condition) = (SELECT min(lower(condition)) 
                                          FROM table)
               ")
```

Comment: If Spark SQL min() works, why not pyspark.sql.functions.min?